# How to match data from two data tables have single row using LINQ or C# other way

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable, webforms

I have two data-table like below getting data from other datatables

```
DataTable dt  
DataTable dt2
```

Datatable dt have below value and every time dt and dt2 have single row values only then easy match them

```
F1    F2   F3    F4
Yes   No   Yes   No
```

Data-table dt2 have below value

```
F1    F2   F3
Yes   Yes  Yes
```

I want to match output like below into Data-table dt3, both on column name

```
F1   F3
Yes  Yes
```

See datatable dt and datable dt2 both have only one row every time, so you can match dynamic  because both have one row only with column name and value, so I not am getting how to match with dynamic using `LINQ` or some other way for better understanding please check the below image

[image]

Comment: why do you think you need linq for doing that ?

Comment: any trick is ok for me please update your answer, if you have other than linq also ok to me and also in question i have mention any other way also ok to me. @Kunal Mukherjee

Comment: Yes, No will be `string` values or `boolean`

Comment: all my rows values are string in both the data-tables. @KunalMukherjee

Comment: Should we match only on `"Yes"` value ?

Comment: no no some time no also should match, please dont pass static yes or no because in future some other values will also there with more column. @Kunal Mukherjee

Comment: Why i am mention red circle because to match like circle only, no need to pass static, for example we check like that  dt.Columns[i].ColumnName. @Kunal Mukherjee

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190892/discussion-between-mohd-mazhar-khan-and-kunal-mukherjee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If without linq is an option then you can try the below method:

```
public DataTable getMatchedColumnAndValue(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
{
   try
   {

      var ndt = new DataTable();
      //creating columns for the table
      var dt1columns = dt1.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(s => s.ColumnName).ToList();
      var dt2columns = dt2.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(s => s.ColumnName).ToList();
      var MatchedCol = dt1columns.Intersect(dt2columns).ToList();
      foreach (var col in MatchedCol)
      {
         ndt.Columns.Add(col);
      }
      //creating columsn matcehd row
      var drnew = new string[MatchedCol.Count];
      for (int i = 0; i < MatchedCol.Count; i++)
      {
         if (dt1.Rows[0][MatchedCol[i]].ToString() == dt2.Rows[0][MatchedCol[i]].ToString())
              drnew[i] = dt1.Rows[0][MatchedCol[i]].ToString();
         else
              drnew[i] = null;
      }
      ndt.Rows.Add(drnew);

      //removing null value columns
      foreach (var col in MatchedCol)
      {
         if (ndt.AsEnumerable().All(dr => dr.IsNull(col)))
             ndt.Columns.Remove(col);
      }

      return ndt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe someone might able to do better but here is mine. ※
Simplified the answer a bit.

```
private static DataTable RegenerateDataTableInCommon(DataTable dt, DataTable dt2)
{
    var dtRows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>();
    var dt2Rows = dt2.Rows.Cast<DataRow>();
    var dtColumnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(dtC => dtC.ColumnName);

    var columnNameMatched = dt2.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(dtC => dtC.ColumnName).Where(colName => dtColumnNames.Contains(colName));
    var cellValueMatched = columnNameMatched.Where(colName => dtRows.First()[colName] == dt2Rows.First()[colName]);

    DataTable outDt = new DataTable();
    outDt.Clear();
    DataRow nRow = outDt.NewRow();
    foreach (var colName in cellValueMatched)
    {
        outDt.Columns.Add(colName);
        nRow[colName] = dtRows.First()[colName];
    }
    outDt.Rows.Add(nRow);

    return outDt;
}
```

Comment: you are answer is giving empty column output. @蕭為元